# Dataset to a table in database

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a Dataset called 'ds' and I want to put that dataset into one of my tables in my sql database. I cannot seem to find a solution for this. How would I go about putting the dataset into a table? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code so far. Dataset that is created from user input:

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = CreateNewDataSet()
    Dim entries As New List(Of String())

    Console.WriteLine("Enter first name: ")
    firstName = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter last name: ")
    lastName = Console.ReadLine()


    entries.Add({firstName, lastName})
    entries.ForEach(Sub(x) ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(x))
```

I'm only using one table, 'Person' with the fields 'firstname' and 'lastname'.

Trying to insert dataset into table Person:

```
     Using connection = New OleDbConnection("connectionstring")

        connection.Open()

        Dim adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim myQuery As String = String.Empty

        myQuery &= "INSERT INTO Applicant (strFirstName, strLastName)"
        myQuery &= "VALUES(?, ?)"

        adapter.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(myQuery, connection)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strFirstName", firstName)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strLastName", lastName)
        adapter.Update(ds)

    End Using
```

Comment: You need some sort of data access.  Using data access you would put your data into the table.  I like using microsoft enterprise library data

Comment: I cannot use Microsoft enterprise library

Comment: Use a data adapter or ADO or something.

Comment: Okay. Will do some research on data adapters. Thank you for your input

Comment: Please post the part of your code that shows your attempt to load dataset into your database. You also need to show the _structure_ of your dataset and the _structure_ of the database table(s) the dataset goes into.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
Private Function CreateObject(ds as DataSet)

Dim connection as OdbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(conString)
connection.Open()

Dim adapter as OdbcDataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from Table", connection)

ds = new DataSet("DefaultName")
adapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Table")
adapter.Fill(ds, "Table")

Dim table as DataTable
table = ds.Tables("Table")

Dim row as DataRow = Nothing
row = table.NewRow()
row("field1") = varField1
row("field2") = varField2
table.Rows.Add(row)

Return ds

End Function
```